# how to set the value of hue and saturation for hsv color image in matlab 2016b

Tags: matlab

.how to set the value of hue and saturation for hsv color image in matlab 2016b

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that your ranges are defined in range of `uint8` (range [0, 255]), and `rgb2hsv` result is double in range [0, 1].

You can multiply by 255 for converting range [0, 1] to [0, 255].

Limiting the range is simple using `min` and `max` functions.

Here is a working exmaple:

```
RGB_Color = imread('peppers.png');  %Read sample image.

hsvImage = rgb2hsv(RGB_Color);

%Convert HSV from range [0, 1] to range [0, 255]
hsvImage = hsvImage*255;

H = hsvImage(:,:,1); 
S = hsvImage(:,:,2); 
V = hsvImage(:,:,3);

%1. Hue value must be in the range between 10 to 40
H = max(min(H, 40), 10);

%2. saturation value(100–255)
S = max(min(S, 255), 100);


%Convert back to RGB
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
hsvImage = cat(3, H, S, V);

%Convert HSV from range [0, 255] to range [0, 1].
hsvImage = hsvImage / 255;

rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Display result
figure;imshow(RGB_Color);title('Original RGB image');
figure;imshow(rgbImage);title('RGB after HSV thresholding');
```

Original RGB image:
[image: Original RGB image]

RGB after HSV thresholding:
[image: RGB after HSV thresholding]